# Connect Spring Boot JDBCTemplate to Azure SQL, Issues with Connection String and TCP/IP

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, azure-sql-database, jdbctemplate

I cannot seem to connect my Java Spring Boot Project to Azure SQL with JDBCTemplate. I keep getting errors, both through Autowired, with connection string, and Option 2) Setting Data Source manually. How can I resolve this issue?
However, both options work with localhost sql database on my computer.

> Error: The TCP/IP connection to the host
> tcp:food-server.database.windows.net, port 1433 has failed.
> Error: "tcp:food-server.database.windows.net. Verify the
> connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is
> running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make
> sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall."

Option 1) `@Autowired` with connectionString in application.properties file, not working

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:sqlserver://tcp:food-server.database.windows.net,1433;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;databaseName=Test
spring.datasource.username=sauser
spring.datasource.password=password12345*
```

Option 2) Configuration Beans with DataSource, currently not working either

```
@Configuration
public class ServerConfiguration {
 
    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        SQLServerDataSource ds = new SQLServerDataSource();
        ds.setUser("sauser");
        ds.setPassword("password12345*");
        ds.setServerName("tcp:food-server.database.windows.net");
        ds.setPortNumber(1433);
        ds.setTrustServerCertificate(true);
        ds.setDatabaseName("test");
        return ds;
    }

    @Bean
    public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate() {
        return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(getDataSource());
    }
```

**Azure IP Security Settings:**

I also made sure to allow my IP Address in Azure SQL Portal, database, Set Firewall

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/firewall-create-server-level-portal-quickstart?view=azuresql

[image]

Comment: I'd say that `tcp:` in your host name should be removed.

Comment: I read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/connect-query-java?view=azuresql

Comment: It gives the start of the JDBC URL as `jdbc:sqlserver://$AZ_DATABASE_NAME.database.windows.net:1433;` so it's clear that there's no `tcp:` in it.

Comment: @tgdavies feel free to write answer, and I can send points, thanks –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The TCP/IP connection to the host tcp:food-server.database.windows.net, port 1433 has failed. Error: "tcp:food-server.database.windows.net. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall."

As @tgdavies commented, the URL you have provided is not in the correct format, which may be the reason you are getting this error. "**tcp: in your host name should be removed**" in your URL.You can provide the URL in the following format:

```java
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:sqlserver://<serverName>.database.windows.net,1433;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;databaseName=<databaseName>
```

By doing this, you should be able to connect to the database successfully. For more information, you can refer to the [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/connect-query-java?view=azuresql#prepare-a-configuration-file-to-connect-to-azure-sql-database) on how to prepare a configuration file to connect to Azure SQL database.